# Fragment vs. FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am new in Android programming. I want to do a Fragment, I have seen examples that uses Fragment and FragmentActivity, What's the difference between them and which cases should be used each one?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FragmentActivity is our classic Activity with fragment support, nothing more. Therefore FragmentActivity is needed, when a Fragment will be attached to Activity.

Well Fragment is good component that copy the basic behaviors of Activity, still not a stand-alone application component like Activity and needs to be attached to Activity in order to work.

Read here [Difference between Fragment And FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

`FragmentActivity` is part of the `google-support-v4` lib which is basically adds a Fragment support to system with OS under 2.3. So `FragmentActivity` is exactly as a simple `Activity` only it gives you the ability to add Fragment to it.

`Fragment` is an object that shares parts of the `Activity` life cycle and can be added as part of you UI to an `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` with it's logic. the beauty of `Fragment`s is that can be reused across different `Activities` in your application.