# setContentView() giving error

Tags: android, android-library

setContentView() is giving error in below is my code :

```
  public class LocateUserInMap extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_user_in_map);
         mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
         mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
         final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(19.111693900000000000,72.911271500000000000);
         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("Friend"));
       //  findDirections(19.111693900000000000,72.911271500000000000,19.128203900000000000,72.928065000000060000, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
    }
}
```

error :
[image]

here is my library that I am using :
[image]

and `activity_locate_user_in_map.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LocateUserInMap" >

 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

what I am missing...
Please help!!!

Regards,
Sourabh

Comment: Post activity_locate_user_in_map.xml

Comment: it looks like that application cannot find R.layout.activity_locate_user_in_map

Comment: @user2376920 you got solution or not?

Comment: no... nothing have worked till yet.

Comment: cleaning of project has not worked. and maps.jar is in GoogleAPI, should I change it to AndroidAPI?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34279/discussion-between-harshid-and-user2376920)

Comment: I have referenced to google_play_service_lib and added to build path but it is errored out as `[2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Success!
[2013-07-27 16:43:59 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!
[2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Starting activity com.example.helpmerestart.Home on device emulator-5554`  can you tell where can I find google-play-services_lib.apk file

Comment: @user2376920 Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file `R.layout.activity_locate_user_in_map` is missing, maybe it is on another project or it is in correct project but somehow it can't be resolved, try to clean the project

Comment: apparently com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment is missing, take a look at examples at 
`Android SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps`

Comment: I have `MapFragment` in import list of my activity class.

Comment: hımm how about google play services lib ? the example on the path I gave should help

Comment: I have referenced to google_play_service_lib and added to build path but it is errored out as [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Success! [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk! [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Starting activity com.example.helpmerestart.Home on device emulator-5554 can you tell where can I find google-play-services_lib.apk file

Comment: hım try with adding the lib .jar file, located at `<path tp android-sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib`

Comment: weird, library projects doesn't include apk files.. are you sure, you referenced the library in right way?http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and this one
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: is there any share point I can share my code so you can look at this and tell what is missing?

Comment: send it to my mail address, mentioned in my profile, i'll do my best to solve.

Comment: Please get it from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwCP4NaaWzvHZXJLcmxHSUotMkk&usp=sharing)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34350/discussion-between-user2376920-and-onur-a)

Answer (score 0):

The @SuppressLint("NewApi") really shouldnt be needed for onCreate() so I am going to guess that you have set your project to the something like:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

And then are trying to use Fragments without using the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).
You will need to change the imports to something like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

And change any calls to:

```
getFragmentManager()
```

to

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

You might also like to checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity) for a good background on Fragment, FragmentActivity and the support lib

Comment: I have given full code of my class. If i remove `SuppressLint("NewApi")` it says `findFragmentById` requires API11. Also both import are showing warning as never used. and min and max sdk guess is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use library directly but only through ActionBarSherlock so I didn't have code to copy and paste here.  I have edited the import part of the answer.  Please make sure to remove the current FragmentActivity import

Comment: **then are trying to use Fragments without using the support library** means? do I need to remove `android-support-v4.jar`.

Comment: If you are going to use fragments without the support lib that you will need to change the <uses-sdk> to 11+ then you should be gtg

Comment: Also you can try following this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: but above link is using min-sdk = 17 and mine is 8

Comment: When: android:minSdkVersion=10 or lower (support library is required); for android:minSdkVersion=11 or higher (no need for the support library but you can still use it)

Comment: yes so I am using support library as androidLminSdkVersion = 8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34283/discussion-between-user2376920-and-corey-scott)

Comment: I have referenced to google_play_service_lib and added to build path but it is errored out as [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Success! [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk! [2013-07-27 16:43:59 - HelpMeRestart] Starting activity com.example.helpmerestart.Home on device emulator-5554 can you tell where can I find google-play-services_lib.apk file