# Android Fragment Code issue

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm wondering how I can get the code below to work with my project as to combine the two so that it could work. What I have is an implemented Navigation Drawer in the app

1st Java Code Using Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

2nd Java Code Using Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AppointmentActivity extends Activity {
Button sendEmail;
EditText msg;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appointment_layout);

    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sndBtn);
    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
            String message = msg.getText().toString();
            sendEmail(message);
        }

    });
}

protected void sendEmail(String message) {

    String[] to=new String[]{"Shop@email.com"};
    String subject=("Shop Appointment");
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Gmail"));
}
}
```

I've tried to combine the two myself but I don't have a lot of experience dealing with android to know how to make both of these codes work side by side and not give me a force close. Anything would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine these codes, you need to declare your `Activity` like a `FragmentActivity` (it will be "host" your `Fragment`). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609839/2668136
And [Google training Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)
Also [Google documentation FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Hope this help.