# How to use Nav Drawer and FragmentActivity together

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

The app won't build properly as I think its looking for fragment `cruisespeed_Fragment` which is actually a `fragmentactivity` when building a navigation drawer. The reason `cruisespeed_Fragment` is a fragment activity is it is a tabbed layout which I put together using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) tutorial.

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new project_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new cruisespeed_Fragment();
                break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new satflow_Fragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new network_Fragment();
            break;
        }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

`And in cruisespeed_Fragment.java`:

```
public class cruisespeed_Fragment extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private CSPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Top Rated", "Games", "Movies"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new CSPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is `Error:(62, 31) error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    cruisespeed_Fragment`

For some reason logcat isn't outputting anything at the moment but once I get that sorted again I will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing your code personally it's difficult for me to speak conclusively, but my understanding is that `FragmentActivity` is an `Activity` used to host an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not an `android.app.Fragment`

As such, you wont be able to launch a FragmentActivity with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
        .commit();
```

You will need to use an `Intent`. Also, ensure you are not accidentally mixing support `Fragments` with regular `Fragments`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity) post goes into good detail on the differences.

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentActivity` extends `Activity` and NOT `Fragment` you need to have your _Fragment() classes extend from some form of `Fragment`