# Onclick of button How to replace FragmentActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have code of replace fragment on button click, but is this possible to replace FragmentActivity??

I have code of replace fragment

```
public void OnClick()
    {
        Fragment frag = new TMSAccountFragment(CurrentViewModel);

        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, frag);
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);
        ft.Commit();
    }
```

Please suggest me for FragmentActivity, thanks.

Comment: To replace FragmentActivity is not feasible. Try to understand difference between fragment and fragmentActivity. Check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity

Comment: NOTE: **FragmentActivity is an Activity, not a Fragment**. Start an activity using Intent. Use FragmentTransaction and FragmentManager to load/add and unload/remove or replace a fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ExampleFragment fragment= new ExampleFragment();

if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.homemain, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

Comment: by using above code you can only replace fragment not fragment activity To start fragment activity you have to use startactivity(new Intent(...);