# Activity or Fragment with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I have 4 modules in an application that are not related to each other. So I previously had created 4 different activities all extending to a base activity that implements the NavigationDrawer. I would like to know if it is better to use fragments over here instead of activity?. I mean, if I make one activity that implements the NavigationDrawer and create 4 fragments for the 4 modules?. Also, what is the difference between Fragment and FragementActivity?

Comment: Also, my application will only support portrait mode.

Comment: FragmentActivity is, well, not a Fragment... And it's deprecated in favor of AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one activity that implements the NavigationDrawer and creates 4 fragments  for the 4 modules. It's better!

`Activities` are designed to represent a single screen of the application, while `Fragments` are designed to be reusable UI layouts with logic embedded inside of them.  According to Google's lectures :[Multi-Versioning Android User Interfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZM8oZBgfk) . `Fragments` makes your code easier to maintain and control.

> what is the difference between Fragment and FragementActivity?

You can see here: [Difference between Fragment And FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609839/5124783)