# onCreateView() method asking for super class call

Tags: java, android

I have extended fragmentActivity class , as far as I read onCreateView is available in lifecycle of fragmentActivity but its not supposed to be calling super class , but its giving me error in @override asking me to call super class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Initializing
    MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override --> error Here
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps,
            container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reportButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Report Button Works",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Log? IDE?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

Not

```
@Override --> error Here
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

You need you Fragments;

**Step 1** - You need create one Fragment.

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Create the view from XML layout.
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, null);

    //Perform additional configuration on layout components here.

    return view;
  }
```

}

**Step 2** - Create Fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);
}}
```

**Step 3** - Create FragmentPagerAdapter
 public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
private List<Fragment> fragmentList;
private Fragment1 fragment1;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    this.fragment1 = new Fragment1();

    this.fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.fragmentList.add(this.fragment1);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //Get fragment in list position
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return size of fragments list.
    return fragmentList.size();
}}
```

**Step 4** - Add FragmentPagerAdapter in your FragmentActivity:

```
this._viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager()))
```

Comment: can you explain the parameters that needs to be passed to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentActivity` doesn't actually have a method called `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`, I think you're confusing it with `Fragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` for which the default implementation only returns null in which case you don't actually need to call the super method.

`FragmentActivity` can act as a host for `Fragments` provided by the support library (regular `Activity` can only host `android.app.Fragment`). In your code you're using the `SupportMapFragment` which extends `Fragment` and overrides `Fragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` to provide its view to the hosting Activity.

For an Activity, you'd typically just set your button click listeners in `onCreate` after calling `setContentView`.

Comment: its given here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: anyway I can use onCreateView() ?? actually I'm trying to listen button events in Fragment, new to android development

Comment: @Mr.A.N events from a button in the SupportMapFragment? or do you have another fragment attached also?

Comment: @Mr.A.N not sure how feasible that would be but I think it'd be best if you would post that as a new question with more detail about what you want to accomplish. Typically you'd extend the fragment you want to modify and override its methods, but SupportMapFragment might not be very compatible with such methods

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentActivity` is used to hold a `Fragment` prior to `API 3.0`. If you're targeting an app prior to `Honeycomb` then you should use `FragmentActivity` but if you're targeting an app after `Honeycomb` then you should use an `Activity`. And remember that the `FragmentActivity` *holds* a `Fragment`, which means that you should attach a `Fragment` and call `OnCreateView()` and other fragment methods on the `Fragment` and not on `FragmentActivity`. 
The way to attach a `Fragment` to `FragmentActivity` is

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = myFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, myFragment).commit();
```

Check out this excellent SO post explaining the difference between `FragmentActivity` and `Fragments`
[Difference between Fragment And FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity)

Comment: While it's true that FragmentActivity brings Fragment support for earlier android versions, it (and other support library things) bring also a lot of fixes and new features, such as nested fragments, for newer android versions. It's generally just better to use support library versions regardless of what android version you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

You should try overriding onCreate and changing it from protected to public.
Plus, either get rid of setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); or change it to  getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.about_main_layout);

setContentView isn't availible only in a fragment Activity's java it must have getActivity(). in front of it.

Also, you need a blank public constructor, it's required, `public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }`

Finally, to my knowledge onCreateView is fine, it's what's around it, so please consider the above posibilites.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.about_main_layout);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    checkLocationPermission();
}
// Initializing
MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); }
```